# Как правильно скрыть кнопку по клику?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Задача вроде и простая, но не очень, на странице будет выводится из базы несколько кнопок со своими функциями, у каждой кнопки будет свой ID, нужно что бы при клике на кнопку она скрывалась и при этом показывалась другая, которая по умолчанию скрыта, нужно что бы все это обрабатывал один скрипт так как этих кнопок будет много на странице (5-10штук), пытался сделать вот так:

```
<button id="id1" onclick="show(id,id2);">On</button>
<button id="id2">of</button>
<script>
function show(id,id2){
document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'block'; 
}</script>
```

но так не работает.

Comment: Вопрос не понятен в одном месте. Если допустим ты вывел 10 кнопок, одна из них активна, то как понять какую следующую из 9 оставшихся кнопок нужно сделать активной ?

Comment: вот в этом и суть, что бы при клике передавать параметры с текущим id и id который нужно скрыть в скрипт onclick="show(id,id2), а скрипт это уже обробатывал

Answer (score 1):

вот немного переделанный Ваш пример.

```
<style>
    .hide {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<button id="id1" onclick="show('id1','id2');">button1</button>
<button id="id2" onclick="show('id2','id3');" class="hide">button2</button>
<button id="id3" onclick="show('id3','id4');" class="hide">button3</button>
<button id="id4" onclick="show('id4','id5');" class="hide">button4</button>
<button id="id5" onclick="show('id5','id1');" class="hide">button5</button>

<script>
function show(id1,id2){
  document.getElementById(id1).className = "hide"; 
  document.getElementById(id2).className = "";
}
</script>
```

Это направление думать. Ведь я так понимаю что Вы не знаете заранее калочество кнопок? каким образом у Вас формируеться сраница, на PHP?

В принципе номер следующей кнопки можно передавать в атрибуте (например `data-btn-next`) кнопки по которой кликаем. В этом случае Вам не нужно прописывать функцию по клику, достаточно просто в цикле ловить события клика на кнопку. Но когда будете создавать свои кнопки нужно будет правильно заполнить этот атрибут.

```
<style>
.hide {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<button id="id1" data-btn-next="2">button1</button>
<button id="id2" data-btn-next="3" class="hide">button2</button>
<button id="id3" data-btn-next="4" class="hide">button3</button>
<button id="id4" data-btn-next="5" class="hide">button4</button>
<button id="id5" data-btn-next="1" class="hide">button5</button>

<script>
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for (var i = 0; i <= buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].onclick = function(e) {
            this.className = "hide"; 
            document.getElementById('id'+ this.getAttribute("data-btn-next")).className = "";
        };
    }
</script>
```